# Trying to Replacing a string in a file using groovy DSL

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to replace `VERSION` placeholders in a file to a variable `version` value, but I'm running into the below error:

```
def versions = ["8.8.0", "9.9.0"]
versions.each { version ->
    def file = new File("$Path/test.url")
        def fileText = file.replaceAll("VERSION", "${version}")
            file.write(fileText);
```

Error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [VERSION, 8.8.0]
```

I'm a newbie to groovy dsl, not sure what I'm missing, any suggestions, appreciated !

Comment: It might just be a poor example, but to mention it: ff that code would work, it
would only ever replace all the occurrences of VERSION with the very first
version from the list.  Next versions would no longer find VERSION in the
(same) file as it's already replaced.

Comment: @cfrick Thanks for your time, yes it was a wrong example, sorry for that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use the groovy file `.text` property:

```
def f = new File('sample-file.txt')
f.text = f.text.replaceAll('VERSION', '8.8.0')
```

and like @cfrick mentioned, there is not much point in performing the replace operation on multiple versions as only the first one will actually find the `VERSION` string.

Running the above on a sample file:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
─➤
```

will result in the string being replaced:

```
─➤ diff sample-file.txt_original sample-file.txt
1c1
< Dolore magna aliqua. VERSION Ut enim ad minim veniam.
---
> Dolore magna aliqua. 8.8.0 Ut enim ad minim veniam.
```

where `diff` is a linux tool for comparing two files.

Comment: Thank You ! Yes the example was wrong !